# Equivalent of !n in bash in vim for ex commands?

Tags: ex-mode, command-history

I'd like to be able to view the last n commands, similar to the `history` command in bash, and then be able to execute the nth command similar to the way it is done in bash by using `!<command number>` is there an equivalent to this in vim?

Comment: No direct equivalent, but try `q:` in normal mode (`:h command-line-window` for details).  You can also edit commands before re-running them from there.  A most useful command, along with `q/`.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly hacky but should work:

```
function! ReExecute(historyNumber)
  " Open the command window
  call feedkeys('q:', 'in')

  " Jump to the desired line
  call feedkeys(a:historyNumber.'gg', 'tn')

  " Execute the command
  call feedkeys("\<CR>", 'tn')
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 R call ReExecute(<f-args>)
```

Now use `R 2` to replay the command at line 2.

Thanks for [user9433424](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/6960/user9433424) for [his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8272/1821).

---

**Edit:** It seems a little hard to use like this, because you execute the command without seeing it, hence this little modification:

```
function! ReExecute(historyNumber)
  " Open the command window
  call feedkeys('q:', 'in')

  " Jump to the desired line
  call feedkeys(a:historyNumber.'gg', 'tn')

  " Copy the current command and quit
  call feedkeys("y$:q\<CR>", 'tn')

  " Add the value into the command line
  call feedkeys(':'.@", 'tn')
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 R call ReExecute(<f-args>)
```

This populate your command line with the nth last command, which is more what you asked in the first place anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer from here: [Using command line history in vim](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history)

Here is a summary to execute your command of choice from command history:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> (opens the command history window)
- use vim browsing keys to go to the command you want to execute.
  Alternately `:n` where n is line number of the command to execute, will
  place you on the line.
- <kbd>CR</kbd> -> (Carriage return) Press enter to execute the command.

If you want to run the last n commands:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>
- yank the number of commands you want to run
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> twice
- `:@"`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! One of our moderators has edited your question to format it (we use markdown, and there's special formatting applied to `<kbd>` tags).